# How can the work done by friction be positive?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, friction, work

I have this energy related problem that i cannot understand [image]
in this problem, I am required to find the velocity of the 4.8kg mass when it hits the ground. I easily solved this problem using newton's second law. That is $$\Sigma F = ma => \Sigma F = -0.360*2.8*9.8 + 9.8*4.8 =37.1616$$ 
$$ W = \Sigma F*distance = 37.1616*1.4 = 52.02624$$
$$ W = \frac12 * (m_1 + m_2) *v^2 => 52.02624 = \frac12 * (4.8 + 2.8) * v^2 => v = \sqrt{\frac{52.02624}{3.8}} = 3.70 \frac {m}{s}$$

however, my professor told me that my approach is problematic and would not work for other kinds of future problems, and that i should use this instead

$$ W = m_2gh = \frac12 m_1 v^2 + \frac12 m_2v^2 + f_kh => 65.856 = \frac12 m_1 v^2 + \frac12 m_2v^2 + f_kh $$

So my question is, how is the work done by friction $f_kh$ positive when it's against the displacement, and how is $ W = m_2gh $ I have never seen work defined this way, i think it shouold have been $PE = m_2gh $ but I honestly am not sure, can someone explain this please

Comment: Just to treat the title question seriously, my usual example is dropping a crate from rest onto a passing flat-car. In the frame of the ground, friction with the train does positive work to the crate. But that is not what you've got here.

Comment: Do you mean that friction should be negative in this case?

Comment: I haven't taken the time to look closely at your question but it is the *net* work $W_{net}$ that equals the change in KE.  In the last line, $m_2gh$ is, I believe, the work done by gravity $W_g$ which must be greater than the net work (change in KE) since there is dissipation.  Put another way, isn't it $$W_{net} = W_g + W_f = m_2gh - f_kh = 4.8 \cdot 9.8 \cdot 1.4 - 0.36 \cdot 2.8 \cdot 9.8 \cdot 1.4 = 65.86 -  13.82 = 52.02\:\mathrm{J}$$

Comment: Isn't this the type of question we *do* want here? OP has a concern about why a particular method isn't valid & wants the generalization explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the time I started solving problems in physics nearly 5 years ago, the most common mistake I've seen people make is trying to introduce 'signs'(into equations). The positive or negative value is purely a matter of convention, I.e., it is based on the coordinate system chosen by you. So I suggest that instead of trying to give the work done by friction a negative sign, just use your axes to give signs to all the forces, displacements and velocities and leave the unknowns with a positive sign. The values of work done and energies(kinetic and potential) will then have signs accordingly.

**EDIT**:
I'm sorry, but I hadn't read your question completely, so I will endeavour to answer your question as completely as possible. I strongly believe that instead of directly taking equations from an outside source, they should derive the equations themselves. Now the equation given to you by your professor is derived from the most fundamental law of physics, **The Law of Conservation of Energy**. It states that the sum of energies of the initial state is equal to the sum of energies in the final state. In case we bring in forces other than the gravitational force, such as friction, we have another term relating to the work done to overcome friction. Now the term $f_k$h relates to the done in overcoming friction as the first mass slides along the table. So the law of conservation of energy for the above case can be written as:
$KE_1$ + $PE_1$ + $W_f$ = $KE_2$ + $PE_2$

Here, the state 1 refers to the initial position while the state 2 refers to the position of the system after the second mass has moved by 1.4 m vertically.

A small clarification of the work done against friction $W_f$. By definiton, the force of friction acts against the direction of motion. Just keep this in mind.

Now let us set our coordinate system. As the pulley is stationary, the centre of the pulley is chosen as the origin. The direction to its right is the positive x-direction while the direction going above it is the positive y. Also the mass moving horizontally is chosen as $m_1$ while the other mass is $m_2$. Now as both the masses are connected by the same rope, their distances and displacements are the same. Hence if $m_2$ moves along the negative y direction by 1.4 m, the mass $m_1$ moves by 1.4 m along the positive x direction. Also let the mass $m_2$ be at a distance of y m from the pulley. Let us assume the coefficient of friction $\mu$ = 0.3.

We then move on to the calculation of the various terms of the above mentioned equation.

$KE_1$ = 0.5$m_1$$v_1^2$ + 0.5$m_2$$v_1^2$

$v_1$ = 0 as the masses are at rest initially. Hence, $KE_1$ = 0

$PE_1$ = $m_1$g(0) + $m_2$g(-y) =  -$m_2$gy = -47.4y J

$W_f$  = $F_f$(1.4)

$F_f$ = -$\mu m_1 g$ as the force friction is in the opposite direction to displacement and hence in the negative x direction.

$W_f$  = -$\mu m_1 g$(1.4) = -11.53 J

$KE_2$ = 0.5$m_1$$v_2^2$ + 0.5$m_2$$v_2^2$ = 0.5$v_2^2$($m_1 + m_2$) = 3.8$v_2^2$ J

$PE_2$ =  $m_1$g(0) + $m_2$g(-y - 1.4) =  -47.4y - 65.86 J

Now if we plug in the above values into the law of conservation of energy equation, we get-

0 - 47.4y - 11.53 = 3.8$v_2^2$ - 47.4y - 65.86

Simplifying, we get-

3.8$v_2^2$ = 65.86 - 11.53 = 54.33

and $v_2$ = $\sqrt(\frac{54.33}{3.8})$ = 3.78 $ms^{-1}$

So the key point to note here, **Never ever change the formula** and **always give signs to the known displacements, velocities and accelerations(and hence forces) only** and finally **give a positive sign to the variable quantities**.

Comment: can you apply what you said to this problem?

Comment: How do you know where to add friction (left or right of equation)? or is the equation written that way by default?

Comment: in your case you added it to the left side, even though friction is neither an initial energy, nor a final energy, I think

Comment: This is a good question. I will use an analogy to support my solution. Now consider water at 20 degrees celsius. If I heat it on a stove, it's temperature increases to 100 degrees celsius. Now how does this temperature increase? It increases because I supply heat. So effectively, at 20 degrees celsius, the water has a certain initial energy. I then add energy to this intial energy and increase the temperature and push it to the new state.

Comment: Relating this to our mechanics problem, the system is at an initial state with an initial energy which is given by $KE_1$ + $PE_1$. Through it's interaction with the surface, it reaches a new state where the total energy is given by $KE_2$ + $PE_2$. As with the case of the water, the energy interaction due to friction is added to(or subtracted from) the initial state. Hence, I've added the term $W_f$ to the left hand side.

Comment: Please be kind enough to note that if there was no friction between the mass $m_1$ and surface, then the total energy in both the states would be equal, i.e., $KE_1$ + $PE_1$ = $KE_2$ + $PE_2$ as you have assumed in your initial attempt.

Comment: I would also advise you to refer to the book - UNIVERSITY PHYSICS by Young and Freedman for any under-grad physics topic. It is a first-rate work that teaches you a sound approach to not just the basic tenets of physics, but also problem-solving.

Comment: Well most definitely check it out, thank you so much for your help